# Site don't want loading at api <19(KitKat)

Tags: javascript, android, html, web, webview

I need to open the site in my application, but it is loaded only on devices with Android 4.4 and newer. But I need to site opened and with older versions of devices. I tried to connect the HTML5, but it seems made a mistake somewhere. 
The site contains HTML5 and JS code. Here's an example of my Activiti

```
WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);
    setView();
    initToolbar();
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    enableHTML5AppCache();
    web.loadUrl("https://mobile.akbars.ru");
}

private void enableHTML5AppCache() {

    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
    web.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    web.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d("ACTIVTTY", "change rotation");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }*/
    /*@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }*/
}

public class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        WebViewActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

At Android 5.0 and later this site can open in default browser but in early versions of Android it open only in google chrome.
**Is there a way to inherit Google Chrome in my webview?** 
Or some another ideas to open this site?

**SITE:** https://mobile.akbars.ru

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, no there is no way to inherit Google Chrome in my webview (older versions). Only simple webview is the solution. According to the version, HTML5 support also need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html

> Reliably build responsive user interfaces with Flexbox. Your app will render correctly on any Android 4.0+ device when you use the Crosswalk Project.